Visualization of Graphs Data
I need to visualize graphs where each pair of nodes connected by a comma represents an edge, and the numeric value represents the intensity of that edge. For instance, ('A', 'B'): 0.71 means that node A is connected to node B with an edge intensity of 0.71. Now, I need to visualize these graphs in python. Here are the graphs data.
Graph 1
('A', 'B'): 0.71
('M', 'B'): 0.67
('N', 'B'): 0.64
('A', 'O'): 0.62
('O', 'B'): 0.60
('N', 'O'): 0.53
('M', 'O'): 0.46
('A', 'N'): 0.18
('M', 'N'): 0.11

Graph2
('ABC', 'ADC'): 0.53

Graph3
('CDE', 'CFH'): 0.28

Graph4
('GHI', 'GMI'): 0.20

Graph5
('XYZ', 'XWZ'): 0.17

Can anyone assist me visualize these graphs clearly?
I tested your code, and I encountered the same issue of overlapping nodes that I had with my own code. I have attached the output image generated by your code for your reference. I used the following command to save the file: plt.savefig('graph_image.png')


Simply use networkx:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

data = {
    ('A', 'B'): 0.71,
    ('M', 'B'): 0.67,
    ('N', 'B'): 0.64,
    ('A', 'O'): 0.62,
    ('O', 'B'): 0.60,
    ('N', 'O'): 0.53,
    ('M', 'O'): 0.46,
    ('A', 'N'): 0.18,
    ('M', 'N'): 0.11
}

Create the graph from your dataset:
G = nx.Graph()
for key, value in data.items():
    G.add_edge(*key, weight=value)

And render components as you wish:
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=123456)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=axe)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=axe)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=12, ax=axe)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight"), ax=axe)


Update
To control edge color based on weights you can use the following snippet:
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=123456)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=axe)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=axe, edge_color=data.values(), edge_cmap=plt.cm.jet)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=12, ax=axe)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight"), ax=axe)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight"), ax=axe)



@jlandercy, thank you a lot for the answer. I am wondering if we show edges with the color intensity (high value get darker color while low value gets light color) instead its values?

@jlandercy I'm encountering an issue with your code. I've updated my post with the details of the problem. Could you please review it and see if you can identify the issue?

I have added snippet for colouring the edge based on weights. I cannot reproduce your issue, I suspect you are plotting multiple graph in a single figure. Explicitly state figure and axe (updated snippet) to get rid of this problem. Don't hestitate to mark as answered if I have addressed your OP.

Thanks for the addition. First, I need just one color on the edges and the high value of a edge should be darker and less value edge should be lighter respectively. Moreover, I tried Explicitly state figure and axe but getting same problem

Feel free to chose the correct color map you feel comfortable with (https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html, eg. : plt.cmap.Blues). As I said, I could not reproduce your issue, exporting fig explicitly created works fine with latest version of Matplotlib and NetworkX. Without anymore debugging details, there is nothing I can do for this issue. Don't forget to accept the answer if it addressed your OP.

Thank you, I will accept your answer, don't worry. Can you please tell me what kind of debugging details I should provide?
